# Cytoscape how to zoom out then zoom in when animating nodes?

Tags: animation, cytoscape.js

I was able to setup buttons that pan and zoom to particular nodes when clicked using animate in cytoscape, but the effect is not very good.  Once you are centered and zoomed into a node, clicking to zoom to another is pretty jarring since you are panning with the view already zoomed in.  It would be much nicer to have the view zoom out a bit while panning, then zoom back in when the destination node gets closer to the center of the view.

I realize that this is probably an advanced technique, but are there any examples that demonstrate this type of behavior?

Answer (score 1):

You can chain animations using promises, making one run after the first is done.  So you can do something like `cy.animation({ zoom: someLevelOut }).play().promise().then( () => cy.animation({ fit: nextNode }).play().promise() )` to zoom out and then fit to the next node.

Comment: When I try the above, I get a "Uncaught TypeError: globalCy.animation(...).play(...).then is not a function(…)".  I tried replacing the fat arrow notation with regular functional notation as well, but the error seems to be with the "then" not being defined.

Comment: You need `.promise()`